# iis website within another site, is it possible/

Tags: iis-7

My client has two iis7 websites `www.myfakedomain.co.uk` and `sub.myfakedomain.co.uk`. They are .net websites running along side each other on the same server.

We want to "move" the content of `sub.myfakedomain.co.uk` so that it appears under `www.myfakedomain.co.uk/sub` but we want them to remain separate applications in iis for operational reasons.

Is this possible? What are our options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  You can create the appropriate virtual directory for /sub, and then convert the directory to an application so that you can assign a separate pool.

Comment: Thanks. In case anyone else is trying this we found that we needed to add location tags to the parent apps config to stop it from inheriting down `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.inheritinchildapplications(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use IIS rewrite rules. I've done this before myself.

The key is to add this 1 more condition at the beginning of the conditions collection:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." negate="true" />
```

Here's a thread with a lot more detail:
http://forums.iis.net/t/1161322.aspx?URL+rewrite+for+subdomain+to+subfolder